# having trouble making a function to find the determinant of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, types, dynamic-memory-allocation

Probably a simple fix, but I keep getting 0 as the determinate when I should be getting 22, I have to use dynamic memory allocation as well. Might be some problem with using floats as I am not completely familiar with how they work with pointers. Honestly don't know what could be causing the function to output a zero.

cpp.sh link to test: http://cpp.sh/5bu2v

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float determinant(float *mat1, int &rows1)
{
    float s = 1, D = 0;
    float *temp = new float[rows1 * rows1];
    int i, j, m, n, c;
    if (rows1 == 1)
    {
        return (*(mat1 + 0 * rows1 + 0));
    }
    else
    {
        D = 0;
        for (c = 0; c < rows1; c++)
        {
            m = 0;
            n = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
                {
                    *(temp + i * rows1 + j) = 0;
                    if (i != 0 && j != c)
                    {
                        *(temp + m * rows1 + n) = *(mat1 + i * rows1 + j);
                        if (n < (rows1 - 2))
                            n++;
                        else
                        {
                            n = 0;
                            m++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            int V1 = rows1 - 1;
            D = D + s * (*(mat1 + 0 * rows1 + c) * determinant(temp, V1));
            s = -1 * s;
        }
    }
    return (D);
}


int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int n = 3;

    int matrix[10][10] = {{1, 2, 3},
                          {0, 4, 5},
                          {1, 0, 6}};
    float *mat1 = new float[n * n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            *(mat1 + i * n + j) = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Determinant of the matrix is " << determinant(mat1, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use the `arr[i][j]` notation instead of its pointer notation for the sake of readability

Comment: i unfortunately have to use it

Comment: I'm not stopping you from using it, but when you are asking for help here think about all of us. Better readability will attract faster help. You should simplify your code as much as possible. Once you get your answer, work with your original code.

Comment: Consider what `temp` looks like when you call `determinant`, versus how that recursive call will interpret that data.

Comment: @ArdentCoder is bang-on right. Start with the stupidest, simplest thing that can possibly work. Take advantage of libraries and other support. Once you have a simple program that works, all of the big application logic is correct, then start adding complications to meet the smaller requirements.

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than having to repeat `*(temp + m * rows1 + n)` or variants of it all over the place, make a function that does it. If you have to have messy code, confine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call into `determinant`, `mat` is a 3x3 matrix stored in a 1 dimensional array.  Visualize it like this:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

You create another 3x3 matrix, `temp`.

You series of loops to fill the `temp` matrix exclude the first row and column `c`, so it ends up looking like this the first time thru:

```
D E 0
G H 0
0 0 0
```

This gets passed to `determinant`, which is expecting a **2x2** matrix.  Since you've passed it something else, what the recursive call sees is

```
D E
0 G
```

When you construct `temp` you need to do it with the smaller matrix size, not the source size.

Comment: defining temp2 as a matrix the size of V1 at the beginning of the code, adding this at line 80, and calling temp2 in the recursive part worked.

`for (int i = 0; i < V1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < V1; j++){
                 *(temp2 + i * V1 + j)   = *(temp + i * rows1 + j);
                }
            
            }`